# SPRESENSEでの画像操作

Tags: opencv, spresense

SPRESENSEにイメージセンサを接続し、撮影した画像をできればopencvを使って操作したいと考えておりますが、opencvをnuttxへ組み込んで動かすことは可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ソニーのSPRESENSEサポート担当です。
お問い合わせの件について、回答させていただきます。

ご存知だとは思いますが、OpenCV はかなり高度な機能が備わった Computer Vision 用ライブラリで、GPU など多くの計算資源があることを前提したものとなっています。
SPRESENSE の計算能力をもってしても、OpenCV が規定している全ての機能をカバーすることはできません。
SPRESENSE では、NuttX Graphics Library を利用できますが、機能が十分とは言えませんので、今後拡充をしていく予定です。

今後ともSpresenseをどうぞよろしくお願いします。